# Postgresql query, parsing json from column

Tags: json, postgresql

Here is my Query

```
select outcome::json -> 'text' as outcome
from "Deal"
where (outcome::json ->> 'selected')::boolean;
```

I am trying to create a column that returns only one value based off a criteria in the json.  When I run this I just get a blank query though.  This is what the json looks like that I am trying to parse

```
[{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: Failed Credit","id":11,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: No Show","id":3,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: No Tax Incentive","id":7,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: Shaded","id":8,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: Other (See Notes)","id":2,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":true},{"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: Renter","id":9,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Not Interested","id":5,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Pending","id":10,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Closed","id":1,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Missed","id":6,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"active","text":"Pitched: Manually Set by Fluent","id":12,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false},{"status":"deleted","text":"Not Pitched: Other (See Notes)","id":4,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":false}]
```

I want to capture the portion that looks like this {"status":"active","text":"Not Pitched: Other (See Notes)","id":2,"color":"DCEBD8","selected":true} and want my cell to just show

Not Pitched: Other (See Notes) based on "selected":true".

I have not been able to get this to work

Any help would be awesome!  Thank you!

Comment: What type is `Deal.outcome`? Could you show us the schema for `Deal`? Does `outcome` contain a JSON array?

Comment: I just looked it up and its a Text @Schwern

Comment: It would be more efficient, and also check that it's valid JSON, if it was changed to `jsonb`.

Answer (score 1):

First you should use the jsonb type instead of json, see the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-json.html) :

> In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as
> jsonb, unless there are quite specialized needs, such as legacy
> assumptions about ordering of object keys.

If you use jsonb, then this simple query shoud provide what you expect :

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(outcome :: jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.selected == true).text') AS outcome
FROM Deal
```

Answer (score 0):

`outcome::json ->> 'selected'` looks for the key `selected` at the top level. If the `outcome` was `{"text":"Not Pitched: Failed Credit","selected":false}` that would be fine.

But it isn't, it's an array. You need to search the JSON array. First, turn the elements of the array into rows with [`jsonb_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE).

```
select jsonb_array_elements(outcome) from deal;

                                              jsonb_array_elements                                 >
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
 {"id": 11, "text": "Not Pitched: Failed Credit", "color": "DCEBD8", "status": "active", "selected">
 {"id": 3, "text": "Not Pitched: No Show", "color": "DCEBD8", "status": "active", "selected": false}
 {"id": 7, "text": "Not Pitched: No Tax Incentive", "color": "DCEBD8", "status": "active", "selecte>
...etc...
```

Then use that as a subquery to search it.

```
select outcome
from (
  select jsonb_array_elements(outcome::jsonb) as outcome
  from deal
) as outcomes
where (outcome->'selected')::boolean;
```

Note: Consider changing it to jsonb; it will be faster and also prevent invalid JSON.